# How to save data into mysql database from laravel route post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the web.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
})->name("upload");
?>
```

and HTML code like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Google drive integration in laravel</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
    
                <br><br><br>
                    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="thing" id="title">
                    <p id="s"></p>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger" value="Upload">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the data that is received in $name variable in the `Route::post` to be saved in the database.
like if I have MySQL database name "registration" having table "books" and I want to save this value in column "URL"
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for checking database table exist or not

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->hasTable('books')
```

this will return true if exist or else return false

for inserting into database

```
  DB::table('books')->insert(['URL'=>$name])
```

Final code will be

```
$tableExist=Schema::connection('mysql')->hasTable('books');
if($tableExist){
 DB::table('books')->insert(['URL'=>$name]);
}
```

Also you can use connection for query insert also

```
  DB::connection('mysql')->table('users')->insert(['URL'=>$name]);
```

Also connection method not required if you are using default connection.

For imports

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Answer (score 1):

First move the file and after that save the records:

```
Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request, Table $table) {
    $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file->move('dirname', $name);
    $table->column_name = "dirname/{$name}";
    $table->save();
})->name("upload");
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to edit your `.env` file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=registration
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secretPassword
```

Inserting your data would work like that

First you need to import the Database class
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Then execute the insert statement

`DB::insert('insert into books (URL) values (?)', [$name]);`

You probably have more then one column inside your table

`DB::insert('insert into books (URL, AnotherColumn) values (?,?)', [$name,'anotherValue']);`

Source [laravel-docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries)

Comment: i just can't tell how much thankful I am right now.

Comment: There is just one more thing, my whole project is in xampp where I am making and running PHP files, now I want that when user click on a button then my laravel project opens, and I want this to work on xampp using localhost/.. path without having to use artisan server. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried few things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan from this post, it opens the project but when I click upload button then it does not work that the path localhost/uploads is not present

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge

Comment: Ok great thanks for your help, it means a lot. I was stuck for days

Comment: Avoid 100% doing `DB::insert('.....')`, use models or at least `DB::table('books')->....`... Avoid using `DB` class as much as possible...

Comment: @matiaslauriti  why? it is recommended in the laravel documentation.

Comment: Please, share the link where it explicitly recommends using `DB::insert()`...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries

Comment: @noah1400 that is nowhere recommending you to use it... You have to learn a lot my friend... You have to read the documentation better as you clearly have no idea why Laravel is so useful related to databases... Read the introduction to it's ORM, [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#introduction)...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I still don't see the problem using `DB::insert()`.

Comment: @noah1400 The idea of using Laravel is not only based on it simple MVC... but also on the ease of use about Models/Entites = data... you use Models not a raw query... you really want to write raw SQL instead of, for example: `User::create(['name' => 'John']);` ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti you are right it's easier and prettier to use models . I just didn't know you can create models on an existing and already configured database

Comment: @noah1400 Awesome, read the documentation I shared, you will see a lot of great stuff !!! And you will stop using `DB::` ! Also, the advantage is for `relations`, you do not need to do `DB::innerJoin` and stuff, eloquent is beautiful.